# conversion of string representing HH:MM:SS.sss format into HH:MM:SS.ssssss format in python

Tags: python

I have string which is representing time in HH:MM:SS.sss format ,Now i have to convert this sting into HH:MM:SS.ssssss format.Please let me know how to do this?

Comment: If my answer isn't appropriate, please clarify the question.

Comment: To be precise, Jon means: `strTime = strTime + "000"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you not just append "000" on the end?

So "13:23:12.345" => "13:23:12.345000"